# Does it make a difference if I remove spaces in tags like <br />?

Tags: html

I keep finding different answers to this question. Some people say that it makes the markup not compatible with older web browsers -- and quote Netscape :) Thus I want to rephrase the question for today (2014), if I remove spaces in tags like `<br />` will it make a difference for a web browser?

Comment: Nope wont change a thing. Those people on Netscape will just have to make do with no line breaks.. lol

Comment: @showdev Definite duplicate. As I've stated over and over again, there is no <br /> in HTML. It works cause browsers work around it and know what you really meant. So save the browsers extra work and don't do it that way. Do what the spec says instead.

Comment: @showdev: I saw that post. It was asked in 2009, so I thought to get a more recent answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to know for sure is to actually test out in the individual browsers you need to support.

That being said, I can say with reasonable confidence that `<br>`, `<br/>`, and `<br />` are all acceptable in *modern* browsers (IE9+ and the latest versions of the others).  In fact they should all be fine with browsers that are even older than that.

The most correct of the three at this point is `<br>` since HTML has no concept of "self closing" tags.  The `<br />` syntax comes from very old browsers that would interpret the `/` in `<br/>` as part of the tag name and choke.  `<br />` prevents this.  This is only technically correct when serving HTML with a particular doctype and content type.